# Close counter overclutters the links on a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, vote-to-close, post-menu

With the new close counter, all of the links that appear under a question no longer fit (at least not when the question has been edited). The delete and flag links end up very close to the mod and share links, making it more likely to click the wrong link.

[image]

Could the spacing (or some other aspect) be adjusted so that this doesn't happen?

I've tried adjusting the size of the browser window, as well as both increasing and decreasing the font size, and the issue is consistent.

If it's browser-specific, I'm currently using IE 9.

Comment: Browser thing, or font size. That doesn't happen for me.

Comment: I've adjusted both the size of the browser window *and* the font size, and get no difference. Might just be an IE thing.

Comment: Could be. I use SeaMonkey (and sometimes FireFox).

Comment: I wonder if this only affects SE 2.0 beta sites? It looks fine for me on SO and its meta.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "votes still needed" denominator will be removed from the close and delete post menu items on the next build (> rev 2013.3.27.896), as it was causing too many layout issues on sites.

You can still get this information in each item's tooltip:

[image]

Comment: Just curious: when casting a close vote, the blue box now says something like "your vote has been recorded". This used to say something like "... more votes are required". Is this only a textual change, or has something else changed as well?

Comment: I don't mind getting rid of the "1 more vote(s)" monstrosity, but it would be convenient to see the remaining vote count when casting delete votes because it's not static like with close votes.