# Expand question width by 2px?

Tags: feature-request, fixed-width

If you go to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551790/replace-values-in-an-array (after my edit goes through) you'll notice that the second code area has a scrollbar because the contents are 2px too wide for the area it's in. This seems odd to me, because the contents use a fixed-width font. Could the width be expanded by 2px to account for the last couple pixels of the last character in such a situation? It just seems visually odd to be able to scroll for 2px in a field with fixed-width characters.

```
This is a sample code space to illustrate my point; why can I scroll for 2 pixels?
```

Comment: How long did it take you to come up with that sample sentence? ;)

Comment: It's much more than 2px on my browser (Chrome on Mac). I suppose it depends on the font as well.

Comment: @Juhana: fair; I'm in Firefox on Windows XP.

Comment: It's about 4px for me on Chrome/Mac.

Comment: Do different browsers interpret % font sizes differently? Or does it really just come down to the installed font?

Comment: Don't we need to expand it further for the next person who wants to paste *83* characters instead of 82? And what of 84?

Comment: I think this highly depends on browsers and screens, so changing it would simply create the same "problem" with a different configuration.

Comment: Widening the question area may also help with [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172721/167443).

Comment: Yeah, it's actually 6px for me.

Comment: Related: [What is the average number of characters in a Code block before scroll bars appear?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82180/what-is-the-average-number-of-characters-in-a-code-block-before-scroll-bars-appe)

Comment: I keep the zoom value at 90%. `=)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can't be fixed for *everyone*. It's completely dependent on which font you actually end up using and how your browser renders that font. There are actually quite a number of different fonts that could be chosen based on what's installed on your system:

```css
font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, serif
```

Sorry, but there's nothing anyone can do. You'll have to set some custom user styles for *your specific situation* if it really bothers you that much.

Answer (score 3):

That's actually the `padding` on the `<pre>` block **not** the width that pushes it off. It may be a better fix to adjust the padding to either 2px or 1%. The below shows what it's like with 2px:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason that those extra pixels seem to be there is from the padding. This is perfectly natural and I would argue that it is by-design. I say that because once you reach a certain width, the scrollbar starts. Sure it is possible that every once in a while the scroll is only a few pixels but the majority of the time it is a longer scrollbar. Adjusting it by 2 pixels would just mean if you added one more character in there it would start scrolling then for only a few pixels.

Consider a user who zooms. When I zoom my screen 10% in then I no longer see a scrollbar as I would assume users with a widescreen might also not see the scrollbar for 2px.

As a result of this expected behavior when I use code blocks I always try to ensure that I put in explicit line breaks when appropriate to prevent any scrolling behavior, as I think most users do.

Comment: +1 for `Adjusting it by 2 pixels would just mean if you added one more character in there it would start scrolling then for only a few pixels.`