# Mobile close link counter is inconsistent

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, mobile-web, post-menu

The mobile view does not display the new `n/total` vote counts like the full site does:

[image: unactioned close link on mobile with vote counter]

This would be fine, but actually casting a close vote changes to the new display:

[image: actioned close link on mobile with new vote counter]

...so this feels kind of inconsistent. I personally have no preference for which option the mobile site should display, but it'd be nice if it picked one and stuck with it.

You'll also note that the space between the user card and the action bar has unexpectedly disappeared, seemingly because the action bar is no longer fully containing the links inside of it.

Comment: Can you stop breaking the site for a while, please? I know this is your job, but, you know, give it some breathing space.

Comment: Yes, stop being so modern.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn This is just payback for it rate-limiting me when posting the town hall digests. It knew it had this coming.

Comment: Oh, in that case, carry on...

Comment: This feature will be removed tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173909/3