# Incorrect display of close vote counts

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, vote-to-close, post-menu

I've noticed this several times, both in the review queues and in question pages. When I click complete a vote to close a question, if there is already at least one close vote visible, the `close (x/5)` is merely appended as `close (x/5) (x+1/5)`

For example:

[image]

This seems like a bug. The `3/5` should have replaced `2/5`.

Comment: The solution? More jQuery.

Comment: I can reproduce this in the review queue, but not on regular questions.

Comment: @animuson I just tried it again on a question page. It doesn't occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173909/3

Comment: So does that fix the text appearing twice or would I still see `(2) (3)`?

Comment: It should fix the incorrect text display.  Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Indeed it does. Just verified.